# How to bind line to the node? in JAVAFX

Tags: java, javafx, line, bind

for example,

```
fLine.setStartX(aNode.getLayoutX());
fLine.setStartY(aNode.getLayoutY());
fLine.endXProperty().bind(bNode.layoutXProperty());
fLine.endYProperty().bind(bNode.layoutYProperty());
```

I want,

```
fLine.setStartX(aNode.getLayoutX());
fLine.setStartY(aNode.getLayoutY());
fLine.endXProperty().bind(bNode.layoutXProperty()+10);
fLine.endYProperty().bind(bNode.layoutYProperty()+10);
```

how can i do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can

```
fLine.endXProperty().bind(bNode.layoutXProperty().add(10));
fLine.endYProperty().bind(bNode.layoutYProperty().add(10));
```